# how to open two different intent using single button in Android

Tags: android

Hello everyone I m making an Android app and I have to open two activities from same button using if else condition.I have no idea how to do it. Plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give some example code for you. First add a Button and give id as btnTest.
Then in your Activity class use the following code.

first declare your button handle variable.

```
private Button btnTest;
```

then in onCreate()

```
{
  ......
  btnTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
  btnTest.setOnClickListener(this);
  ......
}
```

Then add onClick method

```
public void onClick(View v){
{
  Intent intent;
  switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnTest: 

      if(yourcondition1)
      {
           intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity1.class);
           StartActivity(intent);
      }
      if(yourcondition2)
      {
           intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity2.class);
           StartActivity(intent);
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(condition){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MaintActivity.this,Activity1.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                   } else {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MaintActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                   }
                    }
                }
            });
```